# LinalgError, when doing singular value decomposition on sklean vectorizer matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nlp

I'm trying to vectorize a corpus of texts, so i can then represent the proximity of terms to each other in 2d space (a graph). First i create a co-occurence matrix, and then do SVD on it, as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy

docs = ['...', '...' a list of strings, e.g. sentences]
count_model = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1))
X = count_model.fit_transform(docs)
U, s, Vh = numpy.linalg.svd(X, full_matrices = False)
```

I get the following error:

```
LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional
```

What's odd is that my routine has only just started giving me an error message. I've had numpy's linalg svd function working fine, and am trying to figure out what i've changed to create the error. I'd be grateful if someone could explain the error message, and suggest what i can do. Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, always include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message).  It shows exactly which line triggered the error.  In this case, the question title makes it clear that the error occurs when you call `svd`, but it is still useful to see it.

Comment: Have you looked at `X` just before calling `svd`?  A print statement or two might clarify things.  Try `print(X.dtype, X.shape)`.  Is the output what you expect?